# How to do Gap analysis in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I have below data format in excel:

[image: Previous]

I would like to perform a gap analysis which must automatic show the 'gap' filled as below.
[image]

I tried this formula: =RIGHT(J35,1)-RIGHT(K35,1)

But, I'm getting which says #VALUE!

EDIT: I'm trying it in this way.

```
    =IF(OR(RIGHT((J35,1),"None","Done"),RIGHT(J35,1)-RIGHT(K35,1),"-1","Done"))
```

Still problem

Is this required a VBA code? It seems, keeping output of if statement as formula in excel is not possible now.

Any other ways? How to achieve this ( the required details as shown in gap column)? Thanks.

Comment: What is the logic of this gap analysis?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an incorrect use of both the IF and OR formulas. I believe you're trying to do it like this:

If the right character of J35 is a number, subtract the right characters of J35-K35
If J35 is "None", -1
If J35 is "Done, "Done"

This is a nested IF formula. The first formula is available in all versions of Excel, the second formula is available in newer versions.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(J35,1))),RIGHT(J35,1)-RIGHT(K35,1),IF(J35="None",-1,IF(J35="Done","Done")))

=IFS(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(J35,1))),RIGHT(J35,1)-RIGHT(K35,1),J35="None",-1,J35="Done","Done")
```

Comment: What about: IF(OR(J35="DONE",K35="DONE),"DONE",IFERROR(RIGHT(J35,1)-RIGHT(K35,1),-1))

Comment: In case: the Previous is "None" and current is "A3" then the gap should be "-4" .. Any idea - how this should come?